# Unable to install Sitecore.Kernel in new solution

Tags: nuget

I have set up a new solution for `Sitecore 10.2` instance. I have created a new project targeting `.Net Framework 4.8`. When I try to install `Sitecore.Kernel`, I get this error

```
Unable to resolve dependency 'EnterpriseLibrary.Common'. Source(s) used: 'Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages', 'Sitecore'.
```

Output window shows

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package
'Sitecore.Kernel.10.2.0' with respect to project
'Feature\Navigation\GSC.Feature.Navigation', targeting
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.8'

Gathering dependency information took 4.11 sec

Attempting to resolve dependencies for package
'Sitecore.Kernel.10.2.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'

Unable to resolve dependency 'EnterpriseLibrary.Common'. Source(s)
used: 'Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages', 'Sitecore'.

Time Elapsed: 00:00:04.1640715

========== Finished ==========
```

I don't see this error very informative. Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: I can see that you're using only Microsoft Offline and Sitecore sources for nuget. Try getting packages from official package source ( `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` ) - add it in `Tools` > `NuGet Package Manager` > `Package Manager Settings`

Comment: Yes, I think you need to check your NuGet feed source. I am using this. `https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/api/v3/index.json` and able to successfully install this.

Comment: @MarekMusielak Thanks you so much. Adding online source worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you're using only Microsoft Offline and Sitecore sources for nuget.

Try getting packages from official package source:

Add it in `Tools` > `NuGet Package Manager` > `Package Manager Settings`.

[image]